# Is it legal to auction land without telling bidders it's landlocked?

Tags: real-estate, property

I am looking to purchase some land in Texas that is being auctioned for back taxes. It was made clear that the auctioneers will not be telling anybody that the property is landlocked, and they will falsely assume that the land has access to main roads because of a pre-existing road built that is technically not on that property and no easement has been given.

I was also told that it's illegal to tell others at the time of the auction that it's landlocked because that's "cooling the bid."

Is it legal to auction the property without disclosing the VERY relevant detail that the land is landlocked?

Comment: Would a buyer be able to determine that fact by exercising due diligence?  In other words, isn't it a matter of public record?

Comment: "I was also told that it's illegal to tell others..." Who told you this? The auctioneer? And, generally, it is the buyer's responsibility to do their research in public records and determine that the land is landlocked.

Comment: How do you know that there is no easement for that road you mentioned?

Comment: I know there is no easement because I know the people who own the land that borders it on all sides.

Comment: I thought "landlocked" normally referred to areas that do not have access to oceans/large bodies of water. Your meaning seems to be even stricter than that.

Comment: @JAB That is what the word means. This is an entirely incorrect use of it. A better word for this question would be simply "inaccessible" I suppose.

Comment: @animuson Actually the definition of landlocked is "shut in completely, or almost completely, by land" and this is a perfectly acceptable use of the word. In this case the property is surrounded on all sides by other property and has no access to public or private roads. The only way to access it is by crossing private property.

Comment: @leigero I know the definition, and it has nothing to do with having access to roads as in the way you use it in your question. The vast majority of land in the US is landlocked because it doesn't have access to *water*, not because it doesn't have access to roads.

Comment: @animuson I stand by the claim. This term is commonly used in exactly this way. If you have a better suggestion to increase visibility, feel free to offer it up.